# how to remove unity ios keyboard "done" "cancel" button

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

is there a way to hide unity ios keyboard "done" "cancel" button?
and why this button is in english while devices and keyboard is in chinese?

I open the keyboard like

```
_inputFiled.keyboardType = TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumberPad;
        _inputFiled.keyboardType = TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default;
        _inputFiled.interactable = true;
        _inputFiled.ActivateInputField();

        TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, true, false, true,"请输入弹幕(最多20个字)",20);
```

ios:12.2

unity:2019.4.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the IOS default keyboard.

Comment: how? I did openning the TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default keyboard